# SQL запрос. Incorrect number of bindings supplied

Tags: sql

## Searching the pair

```
con = sqlite3.connect('final_id.db')
cursor = con.cursor()
sql = "INSERT INTO IDS (order_id) values('12345')"
cursor.execute(sql)
con.commit()
con.close()
```

Что не так делаю? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

UPD. Упростил задачу и попытался внести в базу запись. Никакой ошибки не вышло. Однако база, пустая. Не могу пока разобраться.

Comment: Попробуйте добавить запятую, у вас кортеж не получился `data = [('12456',)]` Хотя мне казалось там вообще просто кортеж нужен, без внешнего списка, но я точно не знаю.

Comment: а что делает волшебная запись `[('12456')]` ?

Comment: @teran я пытаюсь занести ее в IDS. Исправил.

Comment: Есть некая система, которая получает на вход ID. Например 5555. Она должна заглядывать в хранилище данных и проверять наличие этого ID (5555) в существующей базе. Если нет, то добавить, если есть, то ничего не делать. Пока я пытаюсь просто занести его в хранилище

Comment: я просто не знаю, что это за язык и его синтаксис поэтому спрашиваю. У вас в ошибке черным по белому написано, что у вас есть 1 плейсхолдер `?` в запросе, но на вход приходит 5 значений. Для приведенного фрагмента кода, не зная синтаксиса напрашивается вывод, что каким то чудесным образом строка `12456` распадается на 5 отдельных значений. Поэтому я и спросил, что за синтаксическая штука с этими `[()]` или `()`.

Comment: @teran питаю слабую надежду, что это должно быть число, которое заносится в столбец `order_id`...

Comment: если это просто число то зачем остаются скобки и кавычки? метку ЯП добавьте уж заодно

Comment: @teran да, вы правы. Я чего-то тупанул. Здесь вообще ни причем `()`

Comment: @teran Про 5 значений, мы намекаете на то, что здесь чушь написана? `'INSERT INTO IDS (order_id) values(?)'`?

Comment: Этот код рабочий. Вероятно, смотрите не в ту базу (в другой файл?).

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA нет, смотрю тот. Столбец вижу, значение NULL

Comment: Я запускал этот код - он рабочий. Что-то делаете не так. Триггеры на таблице есть? Как проверяете? Добавьте DDL таблицы в вопрос.

Comment: Вопрос решен. Не там смотрел данные. Спасибо.

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA А как подставить переменную вместо '12345'? Я пробую, ничего не делает.